# redis-sentinel logs flooded with +sentinel-address-switch and +sentinel-address-update

Tags: docker, redis-sentinel

Recently we updated docker swarm to redis-6.2 image. There are master-slave cache and queue set up on 2 swarm nodes, and 3 sentinel services set up to watch them. With 6.2 we use hostname resolution in the redis configuration with "sentinel resolve-hostnames yes" and "--replica-announce-ip" in the cache and queue services command line.
This was working fine in development swarm, but in production it is emitting several log messages per second with messages like

```
+sentinel-address-switch master cache 10.0.1.185 6379 ip redis-sentinel3 port 5000 for 1a21dc3b66fdd1d205e2dbd872d5726e48e07208
```

and

```
+sentinel-address-update sentinel 1a21dc3b66fdd1d205e2dbd872d5726e48e07208 10.0.1.195 5000 @ cache 10.0.1.185 6379 1 additional matching instances
```

The redis services are working, but the excessive logging is a nuisance. Any clue what could cause these repeated log messages?

Answer (score 0):

shutdown sentinel,and add sentinel announce-ip x.x.x.x

refer from: https://rtfm.co.ua/en/redis-sentinel-bind-0-0-0-0-the-localhost-issue-and-the-announce-ip-option/